# Python: when is user input too heavy?

Tags: python, file, input

When does it become worth it to export the user input to a file?

and

If you did export user input to a file, would you place it in the folder you are in then erase it at the end of the script?

Comment: What do you mean export the user input? As in the user has provided you with a lot of data and you want to relieve the memory by temporarily storing it to disk?

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering when it becomes "a lot" and starts to slow down the program.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question as currently stated. How much memory do you have? How much does your program require? What is the percentage of performance increase before you call something "slow"? How many times do you have to access the data? Do you currently have a problem with memory performance? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases there is no time when it is better to create a temporary file and save the user input (which I am assuming is from an input prompt) to it and the read the input from the file. That is just complicating the input process and slowing down your code. You should simply store the input as normal in a variable. Only if you actually wish to save the data for later use would this be useful.

In the special case where you need to save RAM, you could save the user input to the hard drive for later access when the RAM clears up again, maybe after a large function that uses a lot of it. This is extremely rare because the small amount of memory that the user's input takes up will rarely matter especially if you have another function that is using all of the memory.

Here is an example of what you may be doing if you just use the input vs save to a file and then use the input.

Not Saving to File

1. Get Input From User
2. Use input

Saving to File

1. Get Input From User
2. Create a File
3. Save input to file
4. Re-read input from file
5. Use input

As you can see, the only advantage that saving the input to the file has is that you can discard the input in between steps 3 and 4. It is slower and more complicated than simply using the input though.